# Cox Proportional Hazards Model for panel data

Tags: r, cross-validation, survival, cox-model, rms

I want to get the same results of implementing cox-box by R for this SAS code,

```
model (time1, time2) * event(0, 2) = Age / rl;                                     

id ID;

by Imputation;

ods output ParameterEstimates=param;

output out=obs xbeta=score_beta;

run;
```

I would like to ask how I can perform the cox-model in R and taking into account two group variables, the variable **ID** and the **Imputation** variable in the below data.

Frankly, I did this by cph() and coxph() functions and I got different results thans SAS.

```
f = cph(Surv(time1, time2, event%in%c(1,2))~ Age,  data = dat, x=T, y=T, na.action=na.omit, surv=TRUE, stratum(ID), cluster(Imputation) )

f = coxph(Surv(time1, time2, event%in%c(1,2))~ Age, data = dat, id = ID, cluster(Imputation))
```

is it true? the reference event is 0. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to say more about what you are trying to accomplish with the `ID` and `Imputation` terms. You have counting-process data, but have two different sets of such data for the same `ID` Then your `Imputation` values cut _across_ the `ID` values instead of grouping together multiple `ID` values, which is what `cluster()` terms typically do. Provide more information about the goals of this analysis; it's not clear that these models will accomplish what you have in mind.

Comment: I corrected that really.

Comment: You still provided no background information or goals.

Comment: There is still no information on the scientific question that you are addressing. I fear that even if these software commands produce results that they will be meaningless, given the interleaved nature your data. At least, if you claim that SAS and R differ in reported results, show those results in your question so that others can see for themselves. This is also very close to an [off-topic software-specific question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I do not know what do you really by no information, in summary, I want to convert the SAS file to R, that is it.

Comment: It would be malpractice to explain how to code something that leads to a statistically uninterpretable result, which is what I fear might be underlying your apparent problem. At least show the actual outputs from the programs.

Comment: the issue is that I have no permission to publish the data, the data is huge and I just present the header.

Comment: You don't need to publish the data. You need to explain what you are trying to accomplish with your analysis approach, with the crossed structure of `ID` and `Imputation`, particularly given that `Imputation` seems to increase systematically with time interval within each `ID`. You can replace your actual variable names by `A`, `B`, `C` etc for confidentiality, and then show the _output_ from each of the programs with those names thus replaced. Without your showing those outputs in some form I don't see how this site can help you.